# Cylindrical equation to rectangular coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates, cylindrical-coordinates

How would you convert $y^2=9+r^2$ and $x=3r$ from cylindrical to rectangular coordinates? And what would these equations look like on the $R^3$ plane?

Comment: Can you recall me what the R³ plane is ?

Comment: As said by zwim, the first equation has no solution.

Answer (score 1):

If $r$ is a free parameter then $y^2=9+\frac {x^2}9\iff \left(\frac y3\right)^2-\left(\frac x9\right)^2=1$ is an hyperbola.

But if you are talking about the $r$ of polar coordinates then 
$r^2=x^2+y^2=9r^2+9+r^2\iff r^2+1=0$ which is impossible.

Comment: The coordinates are cylindrical.

Comment: Ok, I got puzzled by $\mathbf R^3$ called a plane, so I assumed $\mathbf R^2$ instead. Although, $9r^2+9+z^2=0$ is still impossible.

Comment: Yep, this question seems half-backed.